# Causes and fixing for error : HTTP Error 503. The service is unavailable

Tags: .net, iis

I am a junior developer, today when i finished configuring my new site in IIS 7 and browsed the site got below weird error which i never got it before..

**HTTP Error 503. The service is unavailable**

I googled for answers to fix this, but took me a day to figure out what to do and don't know actually what gone wrong.
After searching few sites, some people saying these error occurs due to the permissions set in the IIS in which the user or password changes causes the error.. but i never changes any passwords..

gone into event viewer and checked the error details and tried to know what is the problem is but did not succeeded, below is the error logged.

**The worker process failed to initialize correctly and therefore count not be started. The data is the error.**

After pulling my hair for a while decided to re-install .NET Framework and i did it. It worked like a charm.. !!

So anybody know why this has been happened to IIS suddenly??
Will this happen again due to some reason cause my boss is asking me whether it happens again which will create huge problem for us.

Any ideas please let me know. Thanks very much.

Answer (score 0):

In relation to IIS, HTTP 503 error happens when application pool of your application goes down (shuts off) due to catastrophic error in application. There are not defined set of reasons why application pool will stop working.
Its may happen due to invalid credentials of application pool's identity or insufficient memory. These are just couple of typical examples, there can be many more reasons based on application's code and how exceptions are handled.

Comment: Thanks for this, in my case also application pool keep stopping when i try running the website.